# Remap Ctrl-A in GNU Screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have been using GNU screen for a couple of days and the `CTRL-A` navigation is beginning to wear on me. How can I remap this key combo and what are some common replacements for these keys? For example, in Vim I use `jj` instead of `<esc>` because it doesn't require me to break my typing form.

**Note:** Alex explains how to map the key combo, however, adding the binding to `.screenrc` did not work for me. I added it to `etc\screenrc` and that worked. The `.screenrc` method seems to work for most people, I am not sure why not on my system.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To make it <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd>, use the following in `.screenrc`.

```
escape ^Jj
```

To quote [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen),

> ```
>  escape xy
> ```
>
> Set the command character to x and the character generating a literal command character (by triggering the "meta" command) to y (similar to the -e option). Each argument is either a single character, a two-character sequence of the form "^x" (meaning "C-x"), a backslash followed by an octal number (specifying the ASCII code of the character), or a backslash followed by a second character, such as "\^" or "\". The default is "^Aa".

Comment: When the changes are made, `CTRL+J` is supposed to function as `CTRL+A` is that correct?

Comment: I have `escape ^Jj^` in my root directory's `.screenrc` file and the user's home directory's file. I rebooted screen and also restarted the ssh session that I was in. None of these worked, I expected `CTRL+J` to behave as `CTRL+A`

Comment: Do you have an extra caret on the end of that? Should be `escape ^Jj`, not `escape ^Jj^`.

Comment: No, sorry for the misunderstanding, that was a typo in the comment. I just checked the dot file again and it's `escape ^Jj` in `.screenrc` I restarted screen just in case the extra caret was ever there and `CTRL+J` still does not work for me

Comment: Maybe there's a conflict with other bindings but I have tried several keys.

Comment: You can also just press Ctrl + a, and type ': escape ^Jj' (like in vi) to change the mapping dynamically.

Comment: This is late and offtopic, but I wonder if this should be the default in screen. I just don't see that mapping working for anyone who really uses the terminal.

Comment: That might be why tmux uses CTRL+B by default; CTRL+A isn't overly ergonomic.

Answer (score 16):

Similar to the solution of @Alex Hirzel but I prefer using keybinding Ctrl+^ (Ctrl+Shift+6) as it is never used in emacs keybindings.

Just write in `~/.screenrc` as follows:

```
escape ^^^
```

Comment: Why does it have one extra caret? Shouldn't it be just `escape ^^` (which doesn't work)?

Comment: The first "^" is interpreted as escape (ctrl key), hence "^^^" sets x to "ctrl-^" and y to "^".

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for remapping the escape bind-key to <kbd>Esc</kbd> , here's the code for you insert into your `/etc/screenrc` or `~/.screenrc`.

```
escape ^[^[
```

In addition, if you want quit by <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> , code the following

```
bind ^[ quit
```

If you want to find out what a key or key combination sends for your terminal, run the following bash command.

```
$ sed -n l
```

---

Reference:

- [Screen User’s Manual: Command Summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Command-Summary)
- [Where do I find a list of terminal key codes to remap shortcuts in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76591/476304)